# Is there a quick way to add tags arround text in html

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, emmet

Say I have some text

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"
```

and I want to quickly add  tags around "dolor sit". I am aware that I can type bold and press tab but then both tags will appear before the "dolor sit"

```
"Lorem ipsum <bold></bold>dolor sit amet,"
```

Is there any shortcut to just add the bold tags directly around the text? (I'm using also emmet)

Comment: Use `<b>Test</b>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Wrap With Abbreviation action: https://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/